# How does serializable_hash super gets the options defined in my overridden method?

Tags: ruby, super

In an active record model, we are overriding the `serializable_hash` method and calling `super options` after setting the options accordingly to our needs.

Generally we do:

```
def serializable_hash options=nil
    options ||= {
      only: [
        :id,
        :special_instructions
      ],
      include: { images: nil },
      methods: [:catalog_item_name, ]
    }
    super options
  end
```

But in one of the models, accidentally, we were **not** passing `options` explicitly to the super method. Nevertheless, it appears to be working just as if we were passing the options.

After reading the [serializable_hash source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb#L71) we can't seem to find any reason for options to be initialized properly in the super method.

Any hints on how this is happening?

Naturally, trying to reproduce the structure in a ruby script does not seem to make it happen the same way.
Here is what we've written to try it out:

```
module MyModule
  def my_module_method options=nil
    options ||= { test: 'Test' }
  end
end

class MyTest
  include MyModule

  def my_module_method
    options = { bingo: 'Bingo!' }
    super
  end
end

puts MyTest.new.my_module_method
```

This will print `{ test: 'Test' }` and if we pass the options (`super options`), will print `{ bingo: 'Bingo!' }` (as we would expect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the (rather old) [pickaxe book (AKA Programming Ruby)](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html#S1):

> When you invoke `super` with no arguments, Ruby sends a message to the current object's parent, asking it to invoke a method of the same name as the current method, and passing it the parameters that were passed to the current method.

So given this:

```
class C
  def m(x)
    puts x
  end
end
class D < C
  def m(x)
    super
  end
end
D.new.m(6)
```

you'll see `6` because the `x` argument to `D#m` is implicit in the `super` when you don't supply any explicit arguments for the parent version of `m`.

Add an argument to the `MyTest#my_module_method` definition and you'll see something.